# Receiving Syntax error near the table name (User)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, syntax

I'm receiving this error

> Incorrect syntax error near "table name"

This is a part of my code

```vb
Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=xxx.xxx.x.x,1433;Database=XX;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User  WHERE  Username=@user  AND  Password=@pass", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim tab As New DataTable
    adap.Fill(tab)
End Using
```

I'm using SQL Server 2022

Comment: `User` is a keyword, what if you use brackets `[User]`?

Comment: oops it worked but i used to use it without brackets and it used to work ,thanks

Comment: And best practice is [not to use AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Yikes, this is not the right way at all to handle passwords or authentication. This is one of those things that's too important to do wrong, even for learning and proof-of-concept projects.

Comment: Realise you've got the problem solved now but just wondering about the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().  Not sure that should be there as you're effectively running your sql query twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` is a keyword, what if you use brackets `[User]`?

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE  Username=@user  AND  Password=@pass", con)
```

Comment: And best practice is to schema qualify e.g. `FROM dbo.[User]`